# Не получается посчитать в T-SQL DateDiff для timestamp в разных строках одной колонки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Это учебная задача, вкратце состоит в следующем:
есть таблица описывающая работу колл-центра и его сотрудников (операторов), а именно есть колонки `Agent_id`, `State_id`, `state_start_timestamp`, `state_end_timestamp`. Колонка `state_id` описывает, что именно сейчас делает оператор в системе ( статусы закодированы по типу:

- **1** - Вошёл в систему,
- **2** - доступен для звонка,
- **3** - говорит и т.д т.п. до
- **7** - выход из системы)

Нужно вывести данные сгруппированные по дню и агенту - сколько агент говорил, сколько был доступен и сколько всего был в системе.
в случае статусов 2,3,4 всё просто

> SUM(case state_id when 1 then DATEDIFF(second, state_start, state_end
> ) end )  GROUP BY Agent_ID

,
а как посчитать всё время в системе ? Сумма всех Case дает число длинною больше суток, я хочу явно прописать datediff статусов 7 и 1 (в рамках одного дня конечно)

---

Буду очень благодарен за совет как лучше всего группировать по дню - на данный момент это реализовано так:

```
datefromparts(datepart(year, timestamp), datepart(month, timestamp), datepart(day, timestamp)) AS calendar_day
```

Comment: То есть записи в таблице (их диапазоны state_start_timestamp - state_end_timestamp) перекрываются, что ли? Тогда конвертируйте данные таблицы в неперекрывающиеся (в СТЕ), а потом уже считайте суммы. Да, рекомендую создать fiddle (или хотя бы выложить CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных) и показать требуемый ответ для этих данных.

Comment: *на данный момент это реализовано так* `CAST([timestamp] AS DATE)` попроще будет...